# UWP connect to ASP.NET Core database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, uwp, asp.net-identity

I have an ASP.NET Core (3.0) app created and running. For some reason I need to create an UWP app which needs to connect a SQL Server database models created by the ASP.NET Core app. Is there an easy way to let the UWP connect to SQL Server? Since the ASP.NET Core app was using ASP Net Identity for authentication, I also want the UWP to use the same user ID / password for grant access to the app.

I know I can add the REST APIs to existing ASP.NET Core app for UWP to access the data, but I cannot find any documents for Web API to use ASP Net Identity to authenticate the system.

Is Web API the easy way for UWP to access the existing data models for my case?

Comment: What do you mean "WEBAPI to use EF Core Identity"? Where do you get this fact?There's no EF Core Identity. There is ASP.NET Core Identity.

Comment: Sorry it is ASPNET Core Identity

Comment: You should not connect the UWP app to your database if you are going to deploy your app to the public users in the Store! You better implement that REST API and for authentication, you can use `Basic Authentication` or if you are want to do more we usually use `token-based authentication` with JWT (JSON Web Token) so look for the term `OAuth 2.0`, ...